# Linux bash script: how to search on a column but return full row?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a tab-delimited file with data like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
```

I wrote a bash script that allows the file to be searched using this code:

```
echo -en "Search term: "
read search

data=`cat data.data | egrep -i "$search"`
```

This works great for searching the entire file, but I'm now wanting to search only on a specific column (which the user can choose).

I am aware of the `cut` command and can search on a column using this:

```
cat data.data | cut -f$col | egrep -i "$search"
```

But then only that column is outputted, so if I use this method then I somehow need to get the rest of the row back.

How can I search on a column in the file, but return the full rows for the results?

Comment: limited to strict bash (use arrays) or can tools like awk be used as well?

Comment: @FredrikPihl Anything can be used as long as it's inside a bash script. I started looking awk but it looked like it was more for replacedment like sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk is easier for this:

```
data=$(awk -v col=$col -v term="$term" 'toupper($col)==toupper(term)' file)
```

col - column number
term - search term

You could also pass field separator with `-F` if needed.

Comment: This would be searching for an exact match instead of a partial match like grep, correct?

Comment: Yes. If you want match like grep, you could use regex match `~` instead of `==`: `data=$(awk -v col=$col -v term="$term" 'toupper($col) ~ toupper(term)' file)`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass two variables to awk: the column number and the search term.

```
awk -vcol="$col" -vsearch="$search" '$col ~ search' data.data
```

If the value of `$col` is 2, then `$2` in awk will correspond to the second column. The `~` operator is used to do a regular expression pattern match. The line will be printed if the column matches the regular expression.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat data.data
col1    col2    col3
$ col=2
$ search=l2
$ awk -vcol="$col" -vsearch="$search" '$col ~ search' data.data
col1    col2    col3
$ search=l3
$ awk -vcol="$col" -vsearch="$search" '$col ~ search' data.data
# no output
```

If you want to do case-insensitive pattern matching, you have two options: convert everything to upper or lower case (`tolower($col) ~ tolower(search)`), or if you are using GNU awk, set the IGNORECASE variable:

```
$ search=L2
$ awk -vIGNORECASE=1 -vcol="$col" -vsearch="$search" '$col ~ search' data.data
col1    col2    col3
```

Comment: You also need to handle case insensitive-ness with `toupper()` or `tolower()`.

Comment: Good point, I've suggested an alternative way to handle case sensitivity.